# UlrLib Downloading image Unsupported Format

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib

wanted to make a tool in order to save images from a specific link, but ecountered a problem.

My code is the following:

```
import urllib

urllib.urlretrieve(url, "img.jpg")
```

The thing is that if I use any link from google it works flawlessly.

For example:

[image: link]
<sub>(source: [asha.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20180609184439/https://leader.pubs.asha.org/data/Journals/ASHANL/934378/NIB1_web.png))</sub>

- works

But if I want to get this specific image:

[image: link]
<sub>(source: [keepeek-cache.com](https://asset.keepeek-cache.com/medias/domain21/_pdf/media3473/533503-b2d468sq50/large/0.jpg))</sub>

It saves the file as .jpg, but when I want to open it I get unsupported file format. Any ideas on how to fix it or what is the reason behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the website is blocking downloads based on the browser signature. Rename your `img.jpg` file to `page.html` and open in a browser, then you will see something like this:

> Error 1010 Ray ID: xxxxxxxxx • 2018-06-08 10:39:01 UTC
>
> Access denied
>
> What happened?
>
> The owner of this website (asset.keepeek-cache.com) has banned your
>   access based on your browser's signature (xxxxxxxxxx).
>
> Cloudflare Ray ID: xxxxxxxxxx • Your IP: xx.xx.xx.xx •
>   Performance & security by Cloudflare

Once you have considered if you want to perhaps contravene the web site owner's wishes, you can change your user agent by doing (for instance)

```
import urllib

# Change user agent to look like Firefox
urllib.URLopener.version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'
# Download file with new user agent
urllib.urlretrieve(url, "img.jpg")
```

which fixed the problem for me.